# What is the formula for combining Hedges' g across studies?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, meta-regression

If I have Hedges g for a bunch of different studies, what is the formula for combining them?

EDIT with more detail. This is part of a meta-analysis. Each study was small, with N usually equal 6 or 8 per group. The measures were continuous (they were amounts of drugs that were self-administered by rats) and each study had 2 conditions (control and treatment).

There were also several covariates including dose of the treatment.

Comment: A little more context and detail would be helpful here, because it looks like a correct answer depends on distributional assumptions and sample sizes.

Comment: @Peter Flom - Reinstate Monica♦ What do you want to do to calculate the "♦ " of Figure 1-4 in the following paper?
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6141619/